# create-react-app build removing css min function

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, build, create-react-app

I have the following in an `SCSS` file for a React app created via `create-react-app`:

```
div.letterCaret {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: css-min(10px, 1.3vh) solid transparent;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-top-color: inherit;
}

div.stringUnderscore {
  height: css-clamp(0.3rem, 15%, 1rem);
  border: $underScoreBorderWidth solid;
  border-top: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: left 400ms $easeOutCirc, width 400ms $easeOutCirc, border-color 400ms $easeOutCirc;
}
```

When I run npm run build, it compiles to this:

```
div.letterCaret {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top-color: inherit
}

div.letterCaret, div.stringUnderscore {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%)
}

div.stringUnderscore {
    height: clamp(.3rem, 15%, 1rem);
    border: .2rem solid;
    border-top: none;
    transition: left .4s cubic-bezier(0, .55, .45, 1), width .4s cubic-bezier(0, .55, .45, 1), border-color .4s cubic-bezier(0, .55, .45, 1)
}
```

On div.letterCaret `border: css-min(10px, 1.3vh) solid transparent;` becomes `border: solid transparent;`. This only happens in build, not `npm run start` (i.e. development), where it works fine. I can't seem to fix it despite explicity calling css functions, what am I doing wrong?

Other solutions tried:

- Creating an `overrides.css` file called directly in the `index.html` head; this works but feels quite hacky, I'd like to know why the above isn't working to understand how to fix it properly
- Importing `overrides.css` into `index.js` straight after the `scss` file, but it's ignored
- Using uppercase Max/Min/Clamp to bypass issues with SASS nativ max/min/clamp
- Using custom functions e.g. css-max to explicitly use CSS functions (current setup); *this seems to work for other uses, just not the border specifically*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `create-react-app` and use `SCSS` then you can install the `node-sass` library by typing:

```
npm install node-sass --save
```

For a full explanation about how to use `node-sass` and `create-react-app` together see "How to Use SASS in Create React App?": https://www.robinwieruch.de/create-react-app-with-sass-support

Also you can have a look on the official docs of `create-react-app`, here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but ```node-sass``` is already installed. Everything else compiles correctly, just not ```border: css-min(10px, 1.3vh) solid transparent;```

Comment: You can find some answers that might help here: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2849

Comment: Yeah that was one of the first threads I looked through, it's where I got the min-css etc functions from to try to explicitly call them. I think it's got something to do with how the styles are being minified as it only happens on the quoted styles above

Comment: Ok, have you tried this? In the node-sass documentation says you have to use --output-style, and it could be nested | expanded | compact | compressed. To minify use compressed. For example: `node-sass -w public/css/scss/style.scss public/css/style.css --output-style compressed`

Comment: So interestingly if I cut out the import of ```style.scss``` (or ```style.css```) in ```index.js``` and call it directly in ```index.html``` the issue is solved, even if I use --style compressed (though I'm using regular ```sass``` not ```node-sass``` as I'm no longer importing"

Answer (score 0):

After much much much digging I *think* this is an issue with the `react-scripts` package using an outdated version of `cssnano` which causes the issue and has [since been addressed in version 5+](https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano/pull/894) but `react-scripts` uses 4.11.1.

To workaround I've switched to using `sass` to compile css and link it directly in `index.html`, which is not really a solution more doing it a different way but I don't understand `npm` well enough to update the nested dependency (I tried and everything broke).